# Android uninstall apk from runtime failure

Tags: android, android-studio

(using android studio) I want to uninstall an apk from my device, using a runtime.
I don't know why if i install an apk it works, but not if I uninstall.
I wrote this code:

```
private int DoAction(String apkPackage) {
    try {
        String res = "";

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su\n");
        DataOutputStream o = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
        InputStream i = p.getInputStream();

        o.writeBytes("pm");
        o.writeBytes(" ");
        o.writeBytes("uninstall");
        o.writeBytes(" ");
        o.writeBytes(apkPackage);
        o.writeBytes("\n");
        o.writeBytes("exit");
        o.writeBytes("\n");
        o.flush();
        p.waitFor();
        res = StreamToString(i);

        return p.exitValue();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return -999999;
    }
}
```

So the DataOutputStream, would be:

```
pm uninstall apkPackage
exit
```

but the res value is always "FAILURE".

I've already added the permission: "android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uninstalling any app just pass package name to this method

```
//calling
     DoAction("your package name");

// method definition
     private void DoAction(String apkPackage) {
      try {
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
           intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:"+apkPackage));
           startActivity(intent);
          }
     }
```

Comment: That's correct! But I want to uninstall the application silently. So, without the final user, tap "OK" to uninstall

Comment: No it is not possible because it is restricted by google due to security reason , you should ask permission from user then uninstall. you may done this to root your mobile first.